# Laravel migrattionで、already exist

Tags: mysql, laravel

Laravelでテーブル、カラムがあるのに、`php artisan migrate`でカラム追加しようとすると、
`already exist`となってしまいます。

`php artisan migrate` で `table already exist` となり、しかし、マイグレーションに入れた一部のカラムしか反映されず。 
↓
そのため、`fresh`して、テーブルごと消して、作り直すことにした。
↓
`php artisan make:migration ●●●‗table`　（テーブルを作成）
↓
しかし、`A Create●●●tabel already exists`（●●●はテーブル名）となりテーブルが作成されない。

想定されること。
★手動でMySQLのテーブルを削除した。コマンドの履歴ではテーブルを削除した履歴がないため、
`already exists`となるのか？

どなたかご教示いただけましたら幸いです。

Comment: migrate:refreshであればresetしてマイグレーションを走らせますが、やろうとしているのは既存のテーブルへのカラムの追加でしょうか？そのテーブルは他のマイグレーションで作成されている？

Comment: 参考: https://readouble.com/laravel/6.x/ja/migrations.html#creating-columns

Comment: テーブルはどうなっていますか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。
学校で質問された内容で、解決されたそうなのですが、今後のためにも、確認して状況、なぜこれが起こったのか、どうやって解決したか、投稿させていただきます。